# WSO2 BAM 2.5 - Default Logger Output Event Adaptor

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep, wso2-bam

Which directory and file does the default logger output event adaptor write the logs to? I am not able to see the logs in the repository/logs/wso2carbon.log  file? The log4j properties file in repository/conf has the default configurations and I can see the mention of wso2carbon.log there. Are there any additional configurations necessary? Please help.

Comment: Default Output Logger log on screen not in files.

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in wso2carbon.log file and also log output adapter should print event logs in terminal console as well.

You can download the log file by System Logs which is located Carbon Management Console > Monitor > System Logs > Show archived logs